# Getting appobject instance from within running COM exe (Office)

Tags: c++, com, automation, ms-office, typelib

I have code running within a COM exe process. Specifically, I have an addin that operates within any Office product.

My code has an `IDispatch*` that is explicitly given to it. Specifically, I am given an `IDispatch*` through my implementation of `_IDTExtensibility2::OnConnection`.

The `IDispatch*` I receive is an interface to a specific coclass that is *not* the coclass which is marked with the `[appobject]` IDL attribute. Specifically, the interface is to a the coclass called `Application` (same name in all Office products), but the coclass marked `[appobject]` within any Office product typelib is called `Global`.

From within this process, is there a way to get the singleton instance of the the `[appobject]` coclass? Here's what I have tried so far:

```
STDMETHODIMP Addin::OnConnection(LPDISPATCH application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, LPDISPATCH addInInst, SAFEARRAY** custom)
{
    // get type info of Application object
    ITypeInfoPtr typeInfoPtr;
    application->GetTypeInfo(0, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &typeInfoPtr);

    // get type lib of Office product
    ITypeLibPtr typeLibPtr;
    UINT typeInfoIndex;
    typeInfoPtr->GetContainingTypeLib(&typeLibPtr, &typeInfoIndex);

    ...
}
```

So I can get the `ITypeInfo*` and `ITypeLib*` for the Application class and its containing type library. I know I can use `ITypeComp*` to bind to global functions/variables by using the `ITypeComp*` returned from `ITypeLib::GetTypeComp`. Something like this:

```
    // get type comp for the typelib
    ITypeCompPtr typeCompPtr;
    typeLibPtr->GetTypeComp(&typeCompPtr);

    // bind to global property-get function "Application"
    ITypeInfoPtr boundTypeInfoPtr;
    DESCKIND descKind;
    BINDPTR bindPtr;
    ULONG hash = LHashValOfNameSys(SYS_WIN32, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, L"Application");
    typeCompPtr->Bind(L"Application", hash, INVOKE_PROPERTYGET, &boundTypeInfoPtr, &descKind, &bindPtr);

    ...
```

However, this is for late-binding these function/variable calls. I actually want to perform early binding -- I have the necessary DISPIDs handy. What I don't have is a `IDispatch*` to the singleton instance of the `[appobject]` class.

Alternatively, I can scan the type lib for the coclass that has the `[appobject]` attribute. However, once I get the `ITypeInfo*` for that coclass, I don't know what to do with it. If I call `CreateInstance` on it, a new process is started as per usual COM activation rules.

How can I get an `IDispatch*` to this `[appobject]` instance?

Comment: Have you tried calling `_Application::get_Parent` and cast the result to `_Global`?

Comment: No luck. The `Parent` property of the `Application` object is returning the object's own `_Application` interface.

Comment: The [appobject] is a convenience in *some* languages, their runtime makes it look like a single instance object that doesn't have to be initialized.  Visual Basic would be an example, you can simply use Globals.Application in the VB code.  C++ is **not** one of those languages, you get no mileage from [appobject].  If you need it for some reason then you are going to have to call CoCreateInstance() yourself.  You should not need it.